# What is the use of transaction mechanism in ENtity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I want to know what is the use of transaction begin, commit and rollback,

I will explain you the example:

1. I need to insert the records to 10 tables.
2. Here using entity framework. So Adding all the entity to dbcontext and
3. after adding 10 entity, then i am going to call the savechanges().

So in this case why i need the commit and rollback, ANy use in this?

Rollback really revert the changes from original database or If all the api process successfully fine then only will insert the records to db in single shot?

Rollback means revert the changes from where?

Could you please explain me to understand this concept?

Comment: You don't need a transaction as SaveChanges internally creates its own. You only need transactions if you call multiple SaveChanges

Comment: Please go to Microsoft documentation for this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions), and as per them: ***Database.BeginTransaction()*** has two overrides – one which takes an explicit IsolationLevel and one which takes no arguments and uses the default IsolationLevel from the underlying database provider. Both overrides return a ***DbContextTransaction*** object which provides ***Commit()*** and ***Rollback()*** on the underlying store transaction.
Now answer to your question: Yes it will work like same as we have a transaction in SQL-Server.

Comment: In addition to multiple `SaveChanges` calls in a DbContext, (generally avoided) explicit transactions or transaction scopes are supported to handle scenarios like working with bounded DbContexts (multiple DbContext definitions for different areas) or wrapping the DbContext operation with other external processes within a single transaction scope that can be committed or rolled back.  When working with a single DbContext and updating a single or set of entities and calling `SaveChanges`, they will either all save, or none of the changes will persist. No need for an explicit transaction.